# Using inputs_for with @conn

Tags: forms, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am attempting to create a form like this:

```
 <%= form_for @form_object, registration_path(@conn, :register), [class: "register_form"], fn f -> %>
    <div class="register_alert">
      <%= Web.PartialView.render("flash_alert.html", conn: @conn) %>
      <%= inputs_for f, :user, [default: %{name_first: nil}], fn fu -> %>
        <%= label fu, :name_first, "FIRST NAME", class: "register_label" %>
        <%= text_input fu, :name_first, class: "register_text-field"%>
      <% end %>
      <%= submit "Sign Up", class: "register_register-button" %>
    </div>
  <%end%>
```

That `@form_object` is a the `conn` passed in at first because I have no changeset until they enter data (create form). However, I keep getting the oh so helpful 'argument error' crash when trying to run this. If I remove the inputs_for section, everything is fine. How do you use inputs_for with a connection object in phoenix?

Phoenix 1.4.0 being used.

Answer (score -1):

[`Plug.Conn`](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#t:t/0) is a `struct` containing nearly everything about the connection.

[`Phoenix.HTML.Form.form_for`](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix_html/Phoenix.HTML.Form.html#module-with-connection-data) accepts the connection object as a first argument.

Since you were even of less help than *Phoenix* providing exactly zero information about the error message, I’d suggest the issue is in a well-formedness of `@form_object`. You clearly have `@conn` object there on hand, pass it as the first argument:

```
<%= form_for @conn, registration_path(@conn, :register) ...
```

Comment: I state that form_object is a conn and the form_for isn't the issue. The inputs_for is the problem, also as stated above. The error I gave is the error phoenix gave me. The question, also as stated, is how to use inputs_for with a conn object. None of this answers that.

Comment: Share the _full_ error message you receive if you expect to receive any help. We are not fortunetellers.

Comment: The question is: How do you use inputs_for with a Plug.Conn object. Do you have an example of that working? Because nothing I have tried has worked and what you've provided is form_for, not inputs_for.